# How do you use the build_native.sh tool?

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I followed [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started) tutorial on raywenderlich.com and I came into a stop on the part where I need to build the native C++ libraries for Android Development.

I am using Mac OS,Cocos2d-x v2.0.1 (latest version), have my Android SDK and NDK set up, and my Eclipse (Helios) with the correct plug-ins needed for C/C++. Now I'm have trouble building the Cocos2d-x libraries for Android development. I'm using the build-native.sh tool. If I use it on the terminal like so:

`xxxxx-xxxxx-imac:proj.android xxxxx$ ./build-native.sh`

I get the following:

```
Using prebuilt externals
Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: /Users/xxxxx/Desktop/LANCE/COCOS2DX/cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt    
Android NDK: /Users/xxxxx/Desktop/LANCE/COCOS2DX/cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1/CocosDenshion/android/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'cocos2dx' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:         
make: Entering directory `/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/LANCE/COCOS2DX/cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1/testproj2/proj.android'
jni/Android.mk:19: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/LANCE/COCOS2DX/cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1/testproj2/proj.android'
```

I looked at `/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/LANCE/COCOS2DX/cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt` but this directory does not exist (the `platform` folder is missing from the `cocos2dx` folder)

How do I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** After looking through the scripts, I noticed that the `cocos2dx` folder in the `cocos2dx root folder` does not have an `Android.mk` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A re-unpacking of the Cocos2d-x ZIP did the trick. Turns out the files needed were deleted (for some reason) in the Cocos2d-x root folder.

Answer (score 0):

build_native tool is obsolete now, Cocos2d-Console is used instead.